# Get filtered value with javascript bigcommerce

Tags: javascript, dom, handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I am trying to display price per unit on a product page. Now the filter that does the math and outputs the value works great but what I need is get the value is displays and access it with javascript to be displayed via a custom module.

Here's the filter:

```
{{#filter custom_fields 'Units per case' property='name'}}
    {{toFixed (divide ../price.without_tax.value value) 2}}
{{/filter}}
```

The output, for example, is  7.68

How do I access the 7.68 value with JS?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it up in html, give it id or class and access it using JavaScript